# How can I add markers in offline mode using MBXMapKit?

Tags: ios, nsurl, mapbox, marker

I am working on iOS Application which requires offline map feature.

When I am trying to fetch markers in offline mode it displaying no image for any marker
even it is not calling method

```
[self asyncLoadMarkerIconURL:(NSURL *)markerURL point:point];
```

As it is only call if data successfully retrieve from URL
and so it is not update marker array for display markers.

So is there any solution to display markers as I created on my map box project in offline map (without internet)?

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions. Mapbox marker imagery is requested from online, which is why you are seeing this behavior.

1. First have an internet connection so that the marker imagery is cached for later offline use.
2. The other approach is to manually fetch the marker imagery ahead of time to bundle with your app. Here is the section where marker URLs are formed based on desired size, color, and imagery:

https://github.com/mapbox/mbxmapkit/blob/d87e1465d196a9948381919da0c1eb8d72a242bf/MBXMapKit/MBXRasterTileOverlay.m#L124

See also standalone markers at https://www.mapbox.com/developers/api/static/.